# Bundler can't find a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cucumber, bundle

Here my Gemfile look like :

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'capybara', '0.4.0'
gem 'cucumber', '0.10.0'
gem 'cucumber-rails', '0.3.2'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'shoulda'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'autotest'
gem 'annotate-models'
end
```

But when i execute **bundle install** i've the problem like

```
Could not find annotate-models-1.0.4 in any of the sources
```

is there any change in rubygems repository ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That gem is called annotate. You can add it with:

```
gem "annotate", '1.0.4'
```

or just

```
gem "annotate"
```

for latest.

Look it up: http://rubygems.org/gems/annotate

Comment: thanks for your response, but about a month ago, when i try execute bundle install in this same Gemfile, everything look normal and the issue about annotate-models is not shown.

Comment: oh thanks for the explanation, i'm new in RoR and my mistake is i think all of version gems is avaible in rubygems repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but about a month ago, when i try execute bundle install in this same Gemfile, everything look normal and the issue about annotate-models is not shown.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Neither removing Gemfile.lock nor changing annotate-models to annotate did the job...

Answer (score 0):

There is no gem on rubygems.org called "annotate-models" you can use http://rubygems.org/gems/annotate

Comment: thanks for your response, but about a month ago, when i try execute bundle install in this same Gemfile, everything look normal and the issue about annotate-models is not shown.